# Cosmos DB Serialization Issue Throws Error Reading An Int as Double

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, jsonserializer

On some of my documents  my .NET Cosmos Db client (v3) will not read a document(s). The document has a property DistanceInMetres and is set to an int on my class.

```
   public int DistanceInMetres { get; set; }
```

When I examine one of the documents causing this error (there are numerous) the property is set correctly.

```
   "distanceInMetres": 3272,
```

The error I receive is:

```
 Input string '3272.0' is not a valid integer. Path 'distanceInMetres', line 1, position 1586.
```

This is the code that does the request:

```
    public async Task<T> ReadEntityAsync<T>(string id, string pKey)
    {
       var doc= await container.ReadItemAsync<T>(id, new PartitionKey(pKey));
       return doc;
    }
```

The serializion error is not depenedent on the client query it occurs on a Container.Read as well as a Container.Query for multiple documents. I tried changing the underlying model property from int to double I still get the same error! I've checked other  documents with the same model that  return with out the error to see if there is any difference but there isn't (That I can see). If I go into the portal and change the property manually while keeping the value the same and update the document the error goes.
I don't believe it's a problem with the data access it happens over single and multiple queries.
Is it a bug on CosmosDB? Has any one any ideas?

As an update:
When I use the DocumentClient to access the database:

```
 DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(new 
 Uri("url"),"Key",                                                         
 serializerSettings: new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new 
 CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() }) ;
```

The document is read with no exceptions.

When I use CosmosClient:

```
   CosmosClient cosmo = new 
   CosmosClient(config["keys:cosmosClientConStr"], new CosmosClientOptions
   {
       ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
       SerializerOptions = new CosmosSerializationOptions { 
       PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase }
        });

        Container container = cosmo.GetContainer(config["keys:dbName"], 
 config["keys:colName"]);
```

I get the exception on SOME documents. The strange thing is if I go into the portal and re-save the document everything is ok.
UPDATE: If I change the class type from T to Dynamic I can read the item back
and it is indeed read as a decimal even though it's stored as a integer.
Here is the stack trace.

`````
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseReadNumber(ReadType readType, Char firstChar, Int32 initialPosition)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber(ReadType readType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadNumberValue(ReadType readType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsInt32()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosJsonDotNetSerializer.FromStream[T](Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosJsonSerializerWrapper.FromStream[T](Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosJsonSerializerWrapper.FromStream[T](Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosSerializerCore.FromStream[T](Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.ToObjectpublic[T](ResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.<CreateItemResponse>b__8_0[T](ResponseMessage cosmosResponseMessage)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.ProcessMessage[T](ResponseMessage responseMessage, Func`2 createResponse)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.CreateItemResponse[T](ResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerCore.<ReadItemAsync>d__56`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.<RunWithDiagnosticsHelperAsync>d__38`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at CT5ApiService.ApiData.CosmosStore.<ReadEntityAsync>d__4`1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\pjsta\source\repos\CT_CLOUD\CT5ApiService\ApiData\CosmosStore.cs:line 81
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at CT5ApiService.Api.JobsApi.<Get>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\pjsta\source\repos\CT_CLOUD\CT5ApiService\Api\JobsApi.cs:line 49
       ````
`````

Comment: Are all documents created the same way? Or is the issue restricted to documents created by a specific user/process/client?

Comment: Seems very odd that the property is not a decimal in the database and is stored as an integer.

Comment: Are you using any Culture for `JsonConvert` call?

Comment: Please show the relevant code that produces the error.

Comment: No I not using any culture the db is in UK South and so am I.

Comment: It doesn't seem that you have provided the actual code that does the query operation...

Comment: Ok I have added the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment:

> if I go into the portal and re-save the document everything is ok

This suggests whatever last modified the item is likely introducing some improper encoding that isn't a true UTF-8 integer value. Your re-save corrects the encoding. Hidden characters can cause [serialization problems](https://jimmybogard.com/the-curious-case-of-the-json-bom/).

A more robust approach is to use the `ReadItemStreamAsync` SDK method to read as a raw `Stream`, then convert to an item using either `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync` or `JsonConvert` on the stream. Then you have opportunity to inspect the raw value and handle any exceptions that arise.

An example is show in the [samples repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/27f3a587bf1fccf3c55fc628d02a121c4b142e73/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/ItemManagement/Program.cs#L237):

```
using (ResponseMessage responseMessage = await container.ReadItemStreamAsync(
    partitionKey: new PartitionKey("Account1"),
    id: "SalesOrder1"))
{
    // Item stream operations do not throw exceptions for better performance
    if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        SalesOrder streamResponse = FromStream<SalesOrder>(responseMessage.Content);
        Console.WriteLine($"\n1.2.2 - Item Read {streamResponse.Id}");

        // Log the diagnostics
        Console.WriteLine($"\n1.2.2 - Item Read Diagnostics: {responseMessage.Diagnostics.ToString()}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Read item from stream failed. Status code: {responseMessage.StatusCode} Message: {responseMessage.ErrorMessage}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunetely this line throw the same error. -  .return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader); However, I think your right there is something amiss when the document is saved. The exception is not thrown using DocumentClient so I will have to implement my class with that instead.